# how to use setter and getter in different functions?

Tags: java

e.x.

```
        class setterGetter{
          String h="null" ;
          setter();
          getter();
        }

        class UseSetterGetter{
            setterGetter sg = new setterGetter();

            public void A{
            sg.setter("abc");
            }

            public void B{
            sg.getter();
            }
        }
```

The problem is, when I wanna use getter in function b, it display "null" instead of "abc".

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: I can't even follow this code what? Where is the `setter(String x)` and `getter()` methods

Comment: They are not just setter and getters. They have some standard format to achieve their functionality also. So please complete your code and then recheck

Answer (score 0):

It will display null because you didn't call method A before that. It should be like this.

```
class setterGetter{
  String h="null" ;
  public void setter(String h) {
      this.h = h;
  }
  public String getter() {
      return h;
  }
}

class UseSetterGetter{
    setterGetter sg = new setterGetter();

    public void A (){
    sg.setter("abc");
    }

    public void B (){
        A ();
    sg.getter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a lot of issues with this code. Keep working on it. Here is what I think you were going for? This is an example of a class with a getter and setter, and another class that is using it.

```
 public class GetterSetter {

    private String aField;

    public String getaField() {
        return aField;
    }

    public void setaField(String aField) {
        this.aField = aField;
    }

}

public class UseGetterSetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetterSetter a = new GetterSetter();

        a.setaField("I am setting the field to be equal to this");

        System.out.println(a.getaField() + " printed");
        // The result of this code is that the system will print:
        // "I am setting the field to be equal to this printed"
    }

}
```